# When I use tesseract to recognize the table, I can't get any output, how can I recognize the table

Tags: ocr, tesseract

Recently, I want to make a tools for Table Recognition. I have tried tesseract ocr, but I can't get any output, can anyone give me the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Highly recommand paddleocr for table recognition! It can output textfile and excel file using just a few lines of code.

```
import os
import cv2
from paddleocr import PPStructure,save_structure_res

table_engine = PPStructure(layout=False, show_log=True, use_gpu=False)

save_folder = './output'
img_path = 'PaddleOCR_pub/ppstructure/docs/table/table.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(img_path)
result = table_engine(img)
save_structure_res(result, save_folder, os.path.basename(img_path).split('.')[0])

for line in result:
    line.pop('img')
    print(line
```

The output files are as follows, which can help you more.

[image]

you can experience it here: https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/PaddleOCR/blob/release/2.6/ppstructure/docs/quickstart_en.md#214-table-recognition